# How can I group by name and then only select the maximum value of each group in R?

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with different observations with repeated names with different values each of them. Example:

```
Name Value Other_attributes
A    20    BLABLA1
B    40    BLABLA2
A    35    BLABLA3
B    10    BLABLA4
C    80    BLABLA5
```

I want a new `data.frame` with only the observations with the maximum values of each group.

```
Name Value Other_attributes
    B    40    BLABLA2
    A    35    BLABLA3
    C    80    BLABLA5
```

I hope to have been enough clear, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with `dplyr`:

Assuming your data frame is `df`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(Value == max(Value)) %>% ungroup
```

***Data***

```
df <- data.frame(Name  = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C"),
             Value=c(20, 40, 35, 10, 80),
             Other_attributes=c("BLABLA1", "BLABLA2", "BLABLA3", "BLABLA4", "BLABLA5"))
```

Comment: You don't need `ungroup` here. Also, could do `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% slice(which.max(Value))`

Comment: I always use `ungroup` at the end after a `group_by`, in the case they do some other manipulation on the data frame. Thanks for the `slice(which.max(Value))`

Comment: This works perfectly with the corrections of @DavidArenburg, thanks to both of you. And sorry for the repeated question, I checked before but I was not able to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, max(Value), by = Name]
```

Comment: If you already overriding `df` just use `setDT`. I've already edited your previous answers and you keep doing it for some reason. Also, this won't match the exact output. You need to use `which.max` with `.SD` here.

Comment: It is good but I loose the other attributes...

Comment: @Laura `setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(Value)], by = Name]`